# Unable to destroy activity Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

I have an application with fragments. I have installed fabric (**Crashlytics**) and I received the same issue that I can't reproduce in emulator. The android that crash is 2.3.4/2.3.5/2.3.6/4.0.4/4.1.1/4.1.2 the rest of versions function correctly.

In my main activity (in destroy function) I have a super.ondestroy();

The error is:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {XXXX.BaseActivity_new}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3316)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3334)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4838)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:642)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.requestFocus(WebViewClassic.java:6938)
       at android.webkit.WebView.requestFocus(WebView.java:2074)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2373)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2329)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2373)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2332)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2373)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2329)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2373)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2329)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2373)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2329)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2373)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2329)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2373)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2332)
       at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6440)
       at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6419)
       at android.view.View.ensureInputFocusOnFirstFocusable(View.java:4373)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3666)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3626)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3558)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1165)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:2083)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:244)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:368)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:203)
       at XXXX.BaseActivity_new.onDestroy(BaseActivity_new.java:878)
       at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5174)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1109)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3303)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3334)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4838)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:642)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Help me? How to solve this issue.

Comment: In `onDestoy()` method are you releasing any object which may be `null`

Comment: Thanks but in my code in function onDestroy() I controll the null value like this `@Override
     public void onDestroy() {
         // Destroy the AdView.
         if (mAdview!= null){ mAdView.destroy();}

         super.onDestroy();
     }` Only crash in the versions that I indicate and aprox. 1% the total of sessions. I think that the problem is about the Fragments